# Why after using strcat function original string changed?

Tags: c++, strcat

well i have two char array . when i try to concatenate both string using strcat function.
Then my string "a" length reduced from 9 to 6. 
i also lost my string "a" .string b changed too.See in the output. why this is happening ???

here is what i have done

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char a[]="roomies!!";
    char b[]="hey kammo DJ ";
    char *c;
    c=new char[50];
    cout<<"before:-\n";
    cout<<"len of a is "<<strlen(a)<<'\n';
    cout<<"len of b is "<<strlen(b)<<'\n';
    cout<<"len of c is "<<strlen(c)<<'\n';
    cout<<"string a is = "<<a<<'\n';
    cout<<"string b is = "<<b<<'\n';
    cout<<"string c is = "<<c<<'\n';
    c=strcat(b,a);
    cout<<"\nafter:-\n";
    cout<<"len of a is "<<strlen(a)<<'\n';
    cout<<"len of b is "<<strlen(b)<<'\n';
    cout<<"len of c is "<<strlen(c)<<'\n';
    cout<<"string a is = "<<a<<'\n';
    cout<<"string b is = "<<b<<'\n';
    cout<<"string c is = "<<c<<'\n';
return 0;
}
```

output:-

```
before:-
len of a is 9
len of b is 13
len of c is 3
string a is = roomies!!
string b is = hey kammo DJ
string c is = =

after:-
len of a is 6
len of b is 22
len of c is 22
string a is = mies!!
string b is = hey kammo DJ roomies!!
string c is = hey kammo DJ roomies!!
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat

Comment: Because, err, that's what `strcat()` does? Have you considered consulting the documentation? instead of just guessing?

Comment: @EJP so why char array "a" changed ?. char arrya  "b"should be only  changed.

Comment: Because you are overflowing `b` and engaging in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Its's C++. Use std::string!.

Comment: @RakeshSharma `cout<<"len of c is "<<strlen(c)<<'\n';` -- Did you expect `50` to be printed here?  You are calling `strlen` on a char buffer that has not been initialized, thus the terminating NULL that `strlen` is looking for could be anywhere.  You also attempt to print out this uninitialized buffer, thus your program has undefined behavior beyond the `strcat` issue.  Why are you not using `std::string`, so that these mistakes aren't made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [strcat spec](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat):

> "The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large
>   enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null
>   character."

Your destination array is "b", which is obviously not large enough to store contents of both "a" and "b", so you got an undefined behavior which resulted in modification of "a" string.

Answer (score 2):

strcat() appends source string to the destination string and returns the destination string.

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

So your statement

```
c = strcat(b,a)
```

So array b and c will have the same values. [strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

EDIT : 
"a" changed because you're overflowing "b" array. Since its c++ you can just use `std::string` instead of a character array.

```
std::string a = "hi" ; 
std::string b = "this is concat" ;
std::string c = a + b ;
```

Comment: got that . but my orignal question is why string "a" changed. while using strcat function.

Comment: @RakeshSharma You didn't get it ... strcat does not return a new char array. b is changed (by appending a).

Comment: @deviantfan  why  "string "a" is changed..!

Comment: @RakeshSharma You know, changing your question after the answer doesn't help anyone. ... Answer: UB. Your code has it multiple times.

Comment: @RakeshSharma "b" changed because that is your destination array. If your question is why "a" changes, it might be because array "b" is not enough to hold the concatenated string. In that case, behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

[strcat on C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

> **Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string.** The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first
>   character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of
>   the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

You may use `std::string` for desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Function `strcat` has the signature `char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src )` and appends the content of string `src` at the end of the string where `dest` points to, i.e. it *alters* the content of the memory to which `dest` points. This requires that the memory to which `dest` points is large enough to hold both strings `src` and `dest`.

Hence, your call `strcat(b,a)` actually yields undefined behaviour, as the memory block represented by `b` is capable of holding 14 bytes (i.e. the length of `"hey kammo DJ "`+ 1), but not for any additional string.

So you'd rather write something like:

```
strcpy (c,b);
strcat (c,a);
```

or:

```
snprintf(c, 50, "%s%s", b, a);
```